# Unable to dispatch redux actions in axios success response interceptor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

Usually we dispatch actions in Axios error response interceptor and it works fine

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (next) => {
        return Promise.resolve(next);
    },
    (error) => {
// Dispatching to handle error 1
        if (error.response.status === 401) {
            if (error.response.data.errorCode === 'USER_LOGIN_ERROR_008') {
                store.dispatch({ type: 'RESET_SECURITY_QUESTION', payload: { id: null, qid: null, question: null } });
            }
     throw error;
    }
);
```

Every successful API response sets a token in user's cookies and if no API is called in the next X minutes then that token will expire

So after every successful API response I need to start a timer in my App.js and once that timer ends would show a Modal to the user that his session has been invalidated

However if a user's actions result in successful API calls  then I want to reset that timer

To reset that timer I would want to call a redux action after every successful API response

So this is what I tried to do

```
axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
    (next) => {
        console.log(`Intercepting ${next.config.url} success response`, next);
        if (next.status === 200) {
             store.dispatch(incrementSessionRefreshTimer());
        }

        return Promise.resolve(next);
    },
```

There is an problem here

Whenever we use axios interceptor to intercept success request, We can modify the request and have to return the request back

What happens in my code is that my action is dispatched but the response is never returned, No lines below `store.dispatch(myAction())` are executed and hence the Component in which I made an API call does not get the success response

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should definitely continue executing after that dispatch. It might cause an immediate rerender, in which case the rerender might happen before the next line, but unless an exception is thrown anywhere, that `return Promise.resolve(next);` line **will** execute. I think your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: I've dispatched many actions in my failure response interceptors too (Conditional dispatches which handle errors for Logout, 401 error, 400 error etc), And the code does not execute after the store.dispatch(action()) line there too

Comment: Wrap it in a `try { dispatch(...) } catch (e) { console.log(e) }` block. Also place a `console.log("test")` in the next line. Generally: this is JavaScript. A method does not suddenly stop executing. That only happens on a `return` statement or when an error is thrown. Otherwise that is just impossible. Nothing Redux-specific there.

Comment: I wrapped the `store.dispatch( . . . )` in try catch as you said and figured out that there was  an error in the reducer and because of that the code was breaking. Now the action is dispatched, Reducer is changing state and response is returned to the component as well. Thanks.